# What is the correct way to round currency data type in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, rounding

I know that float data types cannot be represented 100% accurate. I changed to the Currency data type in my application. I have problems rounding my values. This code reproduces my issue:

```
// uses Math;

var
  Unrounded, Rounded: Currency;
begin
  Unrounded := 6.765;
  SetRoundMode(rmNearest);
  Rounded := RoundTo(unRounded, -2); // was hoping to get 6.77
  showmessage(CurrToStr(Rounded)); // returns 6.76
end;
```

I know that the RoundTo function uses Extended, so what is the correct way to round a Currency?

EDIT: Seems like I have fallen into the bankers rounding method again ^^. Thats why i get 6.76 instead of 6.77... Is there a method to "non-bankers"-rounding?

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569401/recommendable-way-of-rounding-up-currency-values?rq=1) ?

Comment: I just checked it. It's very confusing - i assumed there would be a way to round currency variables, something like "RoundCurrency()", but this wasnt my problem at all - i just forgot that the RoundTo function uses bankers rounding. I changed to SimpleRoundTo and got my calculation working.